# How to execute cron through SSH terminal?

Tags: linux, cron, terminal, debian

I've searched everywhere, but can't seem to find the answer. I'm trying to run this through Linux Debian SSH terminal

```
0 */5 * * * /var/www/test/cron.php
```

And of course there should be some keyword at first to make it run: for example

```
cron 0 */5 * * * /var/www/test/cron.php
```

But it doesn't work. What should I do ?

Comment: The way to install a `cron` entry is to edit the user's crontab. `ssh remote crontab -e` will bring up an editor. If you are unfamiliar with Unix editors, or prefer noninteractive operation, try `ssh remote '(crontab -l; echo "0 */5 * * * /var/www/test/cron.php" ) | crontab -'`

Answer (score 2):

Cron runs on a described schedule, you have the schedule set to `0 */5 * * *` which is "every 5 hours". You can either wait for the 5th, 10th, 15th, or 20th hour for cron to run that command, or just execute the command `/var/www/test/cron.php` from the command line.

```
$ /var/www/test/cron.php
```

Alternatively, you could change the schedule so that it executes (almost) immediately by changing it in the crontab to:

```
* * * * * /var/www/test/cron.php
```

Then changing it back after it runs.